# Google Map is not loading Android - Java

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Here is what I have but my map is not loading and `onMapLoaded` is not being called

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

     <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And then in my class I have

```
public class Activity extends Activity implements GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback {

MapView mMap;
GoogleMap mGooleMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_resturant);

    mMap = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mGooleMap = mMap.getMap();
}

@Override
public void onMapLoaded() {

    Log.i(TAG, "loaaded");
}
}
```

But the onMapLoaded is never called why?

Thanks for the help

**EDIT**

my xml is now this

```
<fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

And I also have

```
public class Activity extends FragmentActivity {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you provided the GoogleMap V2 key?
Along with the key, Google Map needs following permissions which you have to mention in your project's AppManifest.xml.

> **ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE** – To check network state whether data can be
>   downloaded or not
>  **INTERNET** – To check internet connection status
>   
> **WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** – To write to external storage as google maps
>   store map data in external storage 
>   **ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION** – To determine user’s location using WiFi and mobile  > cell data
>   **ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION** – To determine user’s location using GPS OpenGL
>   **ES V2** – Required for Google Maps V2

If all the above mentioned requirements are fulfilled, this code snippet will help you.
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
    // Google Map
    private GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try {
            // Loading map
            initilizeMap();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    /**
     * function to load map. If map is not created it will create it for you
     * */
    private void initilizeMap() {
        if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.map)).getMap();

            // check if map is created successfully or not
            if (googleMap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        initilizeMap();
    }

}
```

P.S Try that `if(mGoogleMap == null)` check to make sure that you do have an instance of Google map.

Comment: I got an error `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #64: Error inflating class fragment` by the way see EDIT

Answer (score 0):

In **Google Documentation they have given an example** [Google Map Example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/)

You can implement **OnMapReadyCallback**  listener which is given in **sample app of google maps** and override the **onMapReady** method as follows:-

```
public class YourCalssName extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);  

     init(); //initialise MapFragment 
    .....
}

private void init() {
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this); // Important to call this method for listener
}

@Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        if (googleMap != null) {
            //Do whatever you want to do
        }
    }
}
```

And in your layout add **Map Fragment** as follows:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" 
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Why do I have to make the map a fragment?

Comment: Why you using mapview??? Same goes for mapFragment. Instead of mapview you can use a mapFragment

Comment: why can't my map view not be a fragment?

Comment: This example given in **Google Map Sample App** where **MapFragment** is used with **OnMapReadyCallback ** listener.

Comment: You didn't link anything? and still why does it have to be fragment?

Comment: See [This Link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/). Its **Google documented Example**